# ImportXML and replacing quotes for enters

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

I'm trying to import a Google Play Store description into a Google spreadsheet, and that works fairly well with this formula:

```
=importXML("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana", "//div[@itemprop='description']")
```

However, I'm running into the issue that this:

```
Keeping up with friends is faster than ever.<p>• See what friends are up to...</p>
```

Will be parsed as:

```
"Keeping up with friends is faster than ever.• See what friends are up to..."
```

Ideally I'd like to see the `<p>` tag replaced by a break, or at least a space. I've been trying the following formula

```
=importXML("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana", "normalize-space(translate(//div[@itemprop='description'],'&quot;',' '))")
```

but this removes every occurrence of &, q, u, o, t and ;

How can I replace these HTML tags for a break or space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use this:

```
=join(char(10),IMPORTXML("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana","//*[@jsname='C4s9Ed']"))
```

which gives you a newline for each

element. Note that for the first example if you want to replace the `•`, you would want to sub that with  a space or new line.

If you just want a space instead of a new line for either of those you can modify the `char(10)` to a `" "` instead.

here is another App page I tried it with:

```
=join(char(10),IMPORTXML("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.orca","//*[@jsname='C4s9Ed']"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(importXML("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana", "//div[@itemprop='description']"), "•"," ")
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, valid answer to this particular use case, but I'd like this to work for all play store descriptions.